# Jenkins Job DSL: how to pass usernamePassword variables to gradle switches?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm creating jobs by seed (not pipeline). This is the part that does not work:

```
            steps{
            wrappers {
                credentialsBinding {
                    usernamePassword('PSQL_USR', 'PSQL_PSW', 'psql-credentials')
                    gradle {
                        tasks("migrate -x test")
                        switches("-Dflyway.user=${PSQL_USR}")
                        switches("-Dflyway.password=${PSQL_PSW}")
                        fromRootBuildScriptDir()
                        gradleName("(Default)")
                        useWrapper(true)
                        makeExecutable(false)
                        useWorkspaceAsHome(false)
                    }
                }
              }
            }
```

getting exception no property PSQL_USR for class. Is there any way to pass credentials to gradle switches? It works just fine in a normal declarative pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working by moving wrappers block with credentialsBinding one level up, getting rid of curly braces and replacing double quotes with single:

```
            wrappers {
                credentialsBinding {
                   usernamePassword('PSQL_USR', 'PSQL_PSW', 'psql-credentials')
                }
            }
            steps{
                 gradle {
                    tasks("migrate -x test")
                    switches('-Dflyway.user=$PSQL_USR')
                    switches('-Dflyway.password=$PSQL_PSW')
                    ...
                }
            }
```